# How to get Length of each line of multiline TextBox and check more or less than specific value in VB .NET

Tags: vb.net

I want to get length of each line in multiline textbox and show in another textbox like 3/12
and check if each line more than 36 Characters then forecolor of the textbox indicating length of lines should be red.
I wrote a cod for that but doesn't work very well.
how can i achive that? thank you all.

My cod is:

```
  Private Sub Texttb_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Texttb.TextChanged


  
        TextBox2.Clear()

        For Each lin As String In Texttb.Lines
            TextBox2.AppendText(lin.Length & "/")
            If lin.Length > 38 Then
                TextBox2.ForeColor = Color.Red
            ElseIf lin.Length < 38 Then
                TextBox2.ForeColor = Color.Black
            End If
        Next
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do the numbers 3/12, 17/9 and 43/9 actually mean? Please provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem. Examples are good but they are no substitute to a proper explanation of the general case.

Comment: It seems maybe those values are actually irrelevant and the question is simply how to change the `ForeColor` of a `TextBox` if any line in a different `TextBox` is longer than a specific number of characters. is that correct?

Comment: @ Yes, that's exactly what i mean
how to change the ForeColor of a TextBox if any line in a different TextBox is longer than a specific number of characters.

Comment: OK, I have read your question again and it seems that what you actually want is all the line lengths combined into a `String` with a backslash delimiter, then the `ForeColor` set to `Red` if any of the lines are too long. Is that actually correct?

Comment: @jmcilhinney yes exactly dear jmcilhinney

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only care about whether any lines are too long then just use `Any`:

```vb
TextBox2.ForeColor = If(TextBox1.Lines.Any(Function(line) line.Length > MAX_LINE_LENGTH),
                        Color.Red,
                        Color.Black)
```

EDIT:

Based on the full problem description that I managed to tease out, this is probably the way to go:

```vb
Const MAX_LINE_LENGTH = 38
Dim lineLengths = TextBox1.Lines.Select(Function(line) line.Length).ToArray()

With TextBox2
    .Text = String.Join("/", lineLengths)
    .ForeColor = If(lineLengths.Any(Function(n) n > MAX_LINE_LENGTH),
                    Color.Red,
                    SystemColors.ControlText)
End With
```